# "Gave up waiting for root device" after removing all kernels

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs

I was running Ubuntu 14.04 and lost all kernels, however I managed to reinstall a kernel by running the live cd and mounting and chrooting into old partitions. (one of the partitions is encrypted)

Now after booting, I get this error:

```
Gave up waiting for root device... 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. 
dropping to a shell...

initramfs _
```

The ubuntu--vg-root is what the unlocked partition goes to. I think it will be back if I unlock the encrypted partition I have. But GRUB is not asking me for a password. How can I fix that?

I am on (initramfs) shell... no cryptsetup/udisksctl available from there.

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/233684/luks-initramfs-boot-problem-dev-mapper-ubuntu-root-does-not-exist-how-can-i .

Answer (score 1):

I needed to generate the initramfs for the newly installed kernel:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: Please add some more detail what this command actually does and why this will solve the problem. Thank you! :)

Comment: did you do that in `chroot`?